# Issues with sound when running program as different user than login-user

Tags: sound, google-chrome, home-directory, ntfs, alsa

I aliased `google-chrome` and whitelisted myself in `sudoers` so now when I type `sudo chrome` it runs `sudo -u chromeuser -i google-chrome &`. (For reasons outlined below) Since all other users besides myself have a home directory on `ext3` this works very well. The only downside is that chrome, when started as `chromeuser`, will not play sound.

**edit:** Moved question to top for clarity

**Background for anyone who's interested**:

I set the home directoy for one of my users to be on an NTFS partiton so that it is accessible from Windows. I'm the only one who uses the computer so I set fuse to allow 777 permissions to that partition. I deleted `/home/me` and created a symlink in it's place that points to the NTFS partition (which is mounted at `/Shared/home`).

Chrome doesn't play well with that configuration because it creates various caches under your home directory and NTFS performance couldn't keep up with it. I fiddled with a few options to chrome (`--user-data-dir --disk-cache-dir`) but I couldn't get 100% of chrome's open files under my control. So my solution was just run chrome as it's own user.

tldr; I started a program as another user, doesn't seem to want to play sound. Is this related to `alsa`?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: It wasn't a sustainable setup, the fault was with Chrome's inability to respect `--user-data-dir` and `--disk-cache-dir`. If those had worked there would be no need for a second user. It may have been fixed by now, I'm unsure as I stopped doing this long ago.

Comment: How about you delete it?

Comment: Might still be useful to someone having trouble with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**Answered in question by OP**

The solution was just run chrome as it's own user.